# Python Collection Counter subtract versus '-'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to pythonic style solutions, and I'm trying to understand how to read the following code, or understand what actually happens

given:

```
s = "bab"
t = "aba"

s_counter = Counter(s) # Counter({'b': 2, 'a': 1})
t_counter = Counter(t) # Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1})
```

what's the difference between

```
print((s_counter - t_counter)) # Counter({'b': 1})

versus

s_counter.subtract(t_counter)
print(s_counter) # Counter({'b': 1, 'a': -1})
```

and what actually happen when you run that code?
on subtract() function it seems like it basically grab each key and find subtract s_counter value with t_counter value.
but I'm not sure with

```
print((s_counter - t_counter))
```

Comment: The behavior demonstrated by the code in question is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects).  Also, comments in Python starts with `#`, while `//` is an operator.

Comment: @metatoaster I found it in documentation. Thank you.. I did not scroll enough.. and yes in python comment is #, I was typing it directly on stackoverflow.. so ended up kind of mix and match languages

Comment: Please be careful not to write code that would raise an error. `//` is an operator in Python, **not a comment**. I went ahead and fixed what you had

Answer (score 1):

The `.subtract` method works *in-place* on a `Counter` object, and accepts mappings (e.g. `dict` or `Counter`s) or arbitrary iterables. Also, it allows for non-positive values.

The `-` operator creates a *new counter object*, and will only contain the positive results (0's and negative values are ignored in the result). It only works between `Counter` objects.

An analogous relationship exists between the `.update` method and the `+` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on juanpa.arrivillaga's excellent explanations, here's some output to help understand difference.

With following example:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> counter_a = Counter("some random message")
>>> counter_b = Counter("even more random message")
```

If we check id of instances - which is unique for each instance - you'll see it's different, so essentially a new instance is created when you use operators.

```
>>> id(counter_a)
2507556487952

>>> id(counter_b)
2507555822864

# Different id
>>> id(counter_a - counter_b)
2507537937808

# resulting instance is not a same instance as counter_a
>>> counter_a is (counter_a - counter_b)
False
```

So there's the main difference, when new instance is created, original instances aren't affected. If original instance is modified, it usually doesn't return anything.

This theme goes in built-in python collections like set, list, etc.

```py
>>> set_a = set("abcde")
>>> set_b = set("cdefg")

# not same instance
>>> set_a is set_a - set_b
False

# original didn't get affected
>>> set_a
{'c', 'a', 'd', 'b', 'e'}

# returns nothing
>>> set_a.difference_update(set_b)

# this time it's affected
set_a
{'a', 'b'}
```

```py
>>> list_a = list("abcde")
>>> list_b = list("cdefg")

# not same instance
>>> list_a is list_a + list_b
False

# not affected
>>> list_a
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# returns nothing
>>> list_a.extend(list_b)

# now affected
>>> list_a
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```